# HTTP Call stuck on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, http

I am developing a WPF application where I am consuming some HTTP API to get data, I am using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class to make API calls, but as soon I call `GetAsync` method of the client I don't get any response back from the API and the debugger just goes away.

Below is the line I am using to make the call where the debugger gets lost

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
```

I don't know why I am not getting any response from the API.

> Note: The API is working on browser as it is a simple GET call.

Comment: Any response? Did you see if any http request has sent to the server?

Comment: Yes I see the response in the Fiddler, but it does not gets received to the application

Comment: But if you debug it the next instruction is executed or it is stopped to that line?

Comment: As mentioned, the debugger never comes to the next line after `GetAsync` call

Comment: Did you try closing Fiddler while debugging?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it both ways

Comment: what is your Base Address set to your HttpClient ? Need more code here to understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but found a better way of doing async calls in an UI application - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Making the HTTP call inside `Task.Run` worked for me, I assume that this has something to relate with UI Thread blocking.

Thanks everyone for the help!!

```
var task = Task.Run(() => {
    var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
});
await task;
```

Comment: This might now be hiding a problem as the result is not handled and there is no check whether or not the Task completed

Comment: Can you please suggest better way of handling the response in that case?

Comment: Exactly the same suggestions that were posted as comments to the question. This 'answer' is simply skipping the error of the original post but doesn't fix the problem which most likely is caused by mis-communication between client and server.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Thanks for making the point clear, I read about best ways of doing the same and went through a beautiful article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx